# Need help with disease on bronze loquat

Tags: trees, diagnosis, diseases

I have a bronze loquat in my front yard and noticed some dark brown spots (see pictures) on the leaves. I need help identifying what the plant disease is and what I can do to get rid of it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did some research, and found this:

http://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/pp/notes/Ornamental/odin011/odin011.htm

Here is another one from Iran, though the image does not appear to be similar to the problem you are facing:

http://www.researchtrend.net/jnbr/jnbr/VOL%203(3)%202014/7%20JNBR_4(2)%20_2015.pdf

Check with a local agricultural college/university or a Master Gardener's group.

I also found this general link with more information: http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/yard-garden/trees-shrubs/management-of-leaf-spot-diseases/

---

Editing per J. Chomel's recommendation, the disease may be "leaf spot" caused by the fungus Entomosporium maculatum. The second link, the paper, refers to other fungi that might cause the leaf spot disease including E. maculatem as well as Alternaria alternata, Monilinia fructigena, Fusicoccum dimidiatum and Spilocea
pyracanthae. The last link adds the possibility of bacterial causes such as  bacterial pathogens Pseudomonas spp. or Xanthomonas spp.

Comment: so if the link die, we'll lose the name of the disease. Could you extract the relevant content for us?